# core.pager for all output from git

Tags: git

Is it possible to use core.pager for **all** output from git?

E.g.

`git branch -av`

Should not wrap lines in my terminal.

`git log` already has paging as expected with `less`.

I'd rather not have to pipe the output of each command to `less` to get this functionality.

I'm using bash 4.3.18(1)-release on OS X (10.9.5) with iTerm2 2.0 and xterm-256color.

Comment: you could write a wrapper function around `git`, but there are even commands which require interactivity. A pager isn't appropriate then. You should be more selective about which commands exactly should show up in a pager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up writing wrapper functions for the commands for which I want this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) will be able to help, considering "`git branch --list`" learned to show its output through the pager by default when the output is going to a terminal, which is controlled by the `pager.branch` configuration variable.
This is similar to a [recent change to "`git tag --list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff1e72483f416ecb58737205163031f54c24e754)" (Git 2.14.2, Sept. 2017).

See [commit 0ae19de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ae19de74f6f5d6c6f9c80899e1ecd611c5b9827), [commit d74b541](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d74b541e0b40be0bf35e836bd8c6cbf653283d4b), [commit ed104fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed104fa9e1016f8ac5f85642ed11e16b09510bea) (19 Nov 2017) by [Martin Ågren (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3b49e1b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b49e1b0e900a88cab9e1b035dac83c0dd6ae2b3), 28 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `branch`: respect `pager.branch` in list-mode only
>
> Similar to [de121ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff1e72483f416ecb58737205163031f54c24e754) (`tag`: respect `pager.tag` in list-mode only, 2017-08-02), use the DELAY_PAGER_CONFIG-mechanism to only respect `pager.branch` when we are listing branches.
>
> We have two possibilities of generalizing what that earlier commit made
>   to `git tag`.
>
> - One is to interpret, e.g., `--set-upstream-to` as "it does
>     not use an editor, so we should page".
> - Another, the one taken by this commit, is to say "it does not list, so let's not page". That is in line with the approach of the series on `pager.tag` and in particular the wording in Documentation/git-tag.txt, which this commit reuses for git-branch.txt.
>
> This fixes the failing test added in the previous commit. Also adapt the
>   test for whether `git branch --set-upstream-to` respects `pager.branch`.